# How can I programmatically detach a ListView from an ObjectDataSource

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a ListView control and 2 ObjectDataSources. By default the ListView is not linked to the ObjectDataSources through the DataSourceID property. So that when the page loads, I have nothing displayed.

Depending on what button gets clicked on the page, I programmatically attach the ListView to one ObjectDataSource, or the other. I can switch back and forth between the ObjectDataSources and it works fine.

But there is also a button to detach the ListView from the ObjectDataSource entirely. I tried to ListView.DataSourceID = "" and that didn't work. The DataSourceID property doesn't get blanked out and remains the same.

How can I programmatically detach a ListView from an ObjectDataSource?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
ListView.DataSource = dt;
ListView.DataBind();
```

this is the easiest way:

```
ListView.DataSource = null
ListView.DataBind()
```

Comment: The last example you show is the only correct one but it also requires a DataBind() subsequent to it. @md1337 There is no concept of "detaching" a datasource, you simply bind it to a null or empty list.

Comment: I didn't realize that you had to bind even after assigning null (since there is nothing to bind as it's null). In the meantime I've found a solution just hiding the ListView but as far as answering my question this is what I was looking for, thx.